# It is possible to create more than one MDI form in a delphi application?

Tags: delphi, forms, mdichild

I developed a mdi application that has in its main form several child windows that are created at runtime. The child windows are custom forms. I want to display those custom forms in another form from the same application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

No, that is not possible using standard VCL. Only the application's MainForm can be the MDI Form. But it should be possible by using win32 directly as shown [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/23574).

Comment: Also refer to my QC report on the same topic (though it is closed as "Won't Do"): http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=12006

Comment: Sorry for the late replay (as i have been involved in another projects). It didn't work. Sorry. When  I create the second mdi form its child windows are painted in the main form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible in the VCL. As I understand it the MDI form is assumed to be the main form (Application.MainForm). I imagine the underlying Windows routines will not have any such assumption, but I think the VCL will not let you do this without some serious hacking.

At various points in the VCL framework, the important MDI messages are sent to `Application.MainForm.ClientHandle`. Now, `ClientHandle` is the MDI container, but for some reason the container for the main form has been singled out.